# Flutter app doesn't show images larger than 2Mb

Tags: flutter

I made a simple app that selects images from the mobile phone gallery and places them in an Image.file. works well for images less than 2Mb. When I select an image larger than 2Mb, it simply doesn't show it and does not send me an error message.

I'm using the image_picker package.

```py
File image;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar( title: Text(widget.title), ),
    body: Center(
      child: image == null ?
        Text('Select an image')
      :
        Image.file(
          image, 
          height: 350.0, 
          width: 200.0, 
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        var tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        setState(() => image = tempImage);
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.image),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the image in a container instead of relying on the image constraints?

Comment: I copied the code into a new project and I have a 4.2 mb file opening

Comment: For the sake of completeness I also opened a 38mb image just to see if it'd work, it does. The issue isn't the plugin or the code. I'm running it on an iPhone XR, latest stable version of flutter, and the latest version of the image_picker plugin.

Comment: I understand, maybe it's due to a problem with my smartphone, I'll try another device.